# GCP) How to keep jupyter session connected after disconnecting jupyter session from my local laptop?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcp-notebook

I keep `jupyter server` running on GCP `VM instance` by `tmux`.
But the problem is that I wanna keep fitting my model after leaving `jupyter server` session from my local laptop

(eg. I turn off my laptop but jupyter session is still alive, fitting model, and I am able to re-connect that session to check status).

The only way I came up with is to use `~.py` and execute `$python3 fitting.py`, but I wanna run and fit model on jupyter notebook to monitor avoiding adding extra code.

If there is a possible way to do so, please kindly teach me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the [Fairing](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/fairing/gcp/tutorials/gcp-local-notebook/) library?  It comes pre-installed with GCP's new [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/).

This library allows you to pack up your notebook and send it off for remote execution.  A new notebook will the executed content will be saved to your GCP Storage bucket.  No active internet connection required once you kick of the notebook run.

You can learn how to use it by creating a new [GCP AI Platform Notebook](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/) and looking at the tutorials folder inside it.  You can also find additional tutorials for Fairing [here](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/fairing/gcp/tutorials/gcp-local-notebook/)